# Вызов метода в laravel c Builder $query в качестве одного из аргументов

Tags: php, laravel, querybuilder

Есть пакет для обмена сообщениями для laravel проектов https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger
в модели [Message](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger/blob/master/src/Models/Message.php) есть метод для получения непрочитанных сообщений для пользователя:

```
public function scopeUnreadForUser(Builder $query, $userId)
    {
        return $query->has('thread')
            ->where('user_id', '!=', $userId)
            ->whereHas('participants', function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                    ->where(function (Builder $q) {
                        $q->where('last_read', '<', $this->getConnection()->raw($this->getConnection()->getTablePrefix() . $this->getTable() . '.created_at'))
                            ->orWhereNull('last_read');
                    });
            });
    }
```

что за объект Builder $query? прочитал в документации, что билдер используется для построения запросов, но не понимаю как заставить работать этот метод? У пакета, к сожалению, нет никакой документации. Запускал так:

```
$msg = new Message();
$userId = Auth::id();
$builder = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder($query);
$msg->scopeUnreadForUser($builder, $userId);
```

Получаю Undefined variable: query

Насколько я понял, $query формируется внутри метода, и нужно передать как аргумент пустой объект...

Comment: Внутрь метода вы должны передать объект типа `Builder`, а ошибка возникает из-за неопределенной переменной `$query` в этой строке `$builder = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder($query);`

Answer (score 1):

Я не работаю в ларавел, но судя по вашему коду предполагаю, что должно быть так:

```
public function yourAction(Builder $builder, Message $msg)
{
   $userId = Auth::id();
   $msg->scopeUnreadForUser($builder, $userId);
}
```

Для создания объектов воспользуйтесь внедрением зависимостей который предоставляет Laravel